# Packets arriving on server not registered by iperf

Tags: networking, tcpdump

This may have a bit to do with the internals of `iperf`.
I set up `iperf -s -u -i 2` on server A (UDP server, supposed to print stats every 2 seconds), and am sending traffic to it from server B. As a prefix, I am aware of some MTU issues on the network, but I am using `iperf` to diagnose them. I send traffic using `iperf -c <server-address> -l 1000 -u` (the size of 1000 is to avoid MTU problems, for now at least). Now, as soon as I send out the traffic, I can see from server A that a connection was received, due to a printed line. However, stats on bandwidth are not printed out every 2 seconds after.

I confirmed that traffic is actually being sent using `tcpdump`. I see packets arriving, destined to the local server and port 5001, which the server does by default, but server A does not print anything regarding bandwidth.

I am leaning towards some sort of local routing issue, but it is a bit odd since the connection is initially established, so I am leaning towards an MTU issue/`iperf` issue of some kind.

Comment: Random guess: make sure you don't have a host firewall (e.g., iptables) dropping the traffic. [If this turns out to be right, anyone is welcome to convert it to an answer.]

Comment: Yeah I made sure to check that before, `iptables` allows everything. Don't know if I made it clear, but the traffic DOES make it to the server, it is just not registered by `iperf`.

Comment: Is ICMP blocked by other firewalls along the way?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Two things: 1. I am not aware of the underlying network and things it might do. The stuff I am seeing above is in fact for the reason of determining issues. 2. ICMP packets seem to go fine, as ping works (similar MTU issues pop up when I make the ping packet larger than a certain size). The main thing I am trying to figure out is why `iperf -s` is not recognizing the packets which did come to the server.

Comment: There are known bugs with Cisco ASAs default configuration + Linux. Try to found out more about your underlying network infra-structure.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'll look into this. Could you provide more context on what kinds of issues would be relevant here? Again I see the packets arrive to the server through `tcpdump`, but it's not recognized by `iperf`. Not sure if it's invalid checksums or whatnot (don't know the internal workings of `iperf`).

Comment: MTU issues/performance issues/dropped packets/dropped TCP transmissions.

Comment: Have you find out anything else?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks for checking in, unfortunately not, but I am talking with the underlay folks later to check on their configurations.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Windows 10, solved it by opened windows firewall manager (wf.wsc) and add an entry to allow imperf